# How to link to qaxserver.def entities properly

Tags: qt, activex, activeqt

all
I'm trying to create ActiveX server with Qt5.2.0.
According to some pieces of information I have, to create a simple ActiveX server (which exports one object) it's enough to:

1. have such .pro file

   ```
   TEMPLATE = lib
   CONFIG  += dll axserver
   TARGET = simpleServer

   greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
                                     QT += core
   RC_FILE = qaxserver.rc
   DEF_FILE = qaxserver.def

   HEADERS += myserver.h

   SOURCES += main.cpp
   SOURCES += myserver.cpp
   ```
2. have such main.cpp file

   #include "ActiveQt/QAxFactory"

   #include "myserver.h"

   QAXFACTORY_DEFAULT( MyServer, 5 id's )
3. the class should inherit `QWidget` and `QAxBindable`
4. there should be file `qaxserver.rc`. in my case it's content is `1 TYPELIB "simpleServer.pro"`
5. there should be fie `qaxserver.def` with default contents:

   ```
   ; mfc_test.def : Declares the module parameters.

   EXPORTS

   DllCanUnloadNow      PRIVATE

   DllGetClassObject    PRIVATE

   DllRegisterServer    PRIVATE

   DllUnregisterServer  PRIVATE

   DumpIDL              PRIVATE
   ```

the problem is that these 5 names are undefined for Visual Studio's linker.
How to solve the problem?

the error is:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol DllCanUnloadNow
```

Answer (score 1):

need to add  `QT += axserver` in `.pro` file